# Bash pass an associative array to/from a background function

Tags: bash, associative-array

I am trying to pass a bash associative array by reference into a function and then be able to see the changed content back in the main script after the function is complete. I have found what seems to be the most straightforward way to do it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462089/21348) except in my case the function is being run ***in the background***. It seems that no matter what I do, I can't get the linked solution above to work in this scenario.

In the snippet below, I've taken the working example code from the link above and simply added a "&" to the function call and a "wait" on the following line to demonstrate the issue as simply as possible.

I suspect bash is trying to prevent the main script and the background function from stepping on each other, but I don't know how to solve it.

**Example Code:**

```
foo () {
    declare -n fooarray="$1"
    fooarray["fookey"]=foovalue
}

declare -A myarray

myarray["mainkey"]=mainvalue
foo myarray &
wait

for key in "${!myarray[@]}"; do
    printf '%s = %s\n' "$key" "${myarray[$key]}"
done
```

**Output:**

```
bash-4.4$ ./test.sh
mainkey = mainvalue
```

Any help would be appreciated. I know I could potentially do silly things like writing the contents of the array out to a file and then parsing it back in, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution than that.

Comment: To communicate between 2 processes you need either some form of shared memory or some form of InterProcess Communication. Bash doesn't have native support for shared memory, and only limited support for bi-directional IPC. Reading and writing files is simple, I suggest you use it.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: A function run in the background is a separate process. At the time of backgrounding, the child is given a copy of the data. Any changes made to that copy do not propagate to the parent.**

---

Let's put some line numbers on the code:

```
     1  foo () {
     2      declare -n fooarray="$1"
     3      fooarray["fookey"]=foovalue
     4  }
     5  
     6  declare -A myarray
     7  
     8  myarray["mainkey"]=mainvalue
     9  foo myarray &
    10  wait
    11  
    12  for key in "${!myarray[@]}"; do
    13      printf '%s = %s\n' "$key" "${myarray[$key]}"
    14  done
```

At line 9, bash forks itself into two processes: one is the parent, which continues running and stops at the `wait` on line 10; the other is the child, which runs the contents of the function foo using a copy of the data as it existed prior to line 9.

Observe: the parent never runs the code in function `foo`, and the child only runs lines 2 and 3.

In the child, line 2 does the array reference look-up as explained in the other, linked answer. `fooarray["mainkey"]` has the value "mainvalue" in the child, because of the copy operation mentioned. Line 3 then adds the "fookey", but is doing it on *a copy* of the data. After line 3, the child exits with success because the assignment on line 3 succeeded.

Since the parent never runs `foo`, and the child modifies a copy, the parent never sees the `"fookey"` change.

If you want child to modify parent, then you'll have to use a durable interprocess communication mechanism ("IPC", like files or pipes), and have the parent "opt-in" by reading from that IPC and updating its copy of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Though it may not be the most elegant, and it doesn't quite answer your question exactly (this would not modify the array in place), you could output the modified array from the background function like a normal return (ish) then use process substitution to capture the output and copy the update yourself.

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
 2   
 3 foo () {
 4   declare -n fooarray="$1"
 5   fooarray["fookey"]=foovalue
 6   echo "${fooarray[@]@K}"
 7 } 
 8   
 9 declare -A myarray
10 myarray["mainkey"]=mainvalue
11  
12 # Execute "foo myarray" asynchronously using [process substitution][1]
13 # No need to run it in the background (I.e. using "&")
14 exec 3< <(foo myarray)
15 p=$!
16 wait $p
17  
18 echo "<pre> ${myarray[*]@A}"
19  
20 # Capture the return into an array
21 # Bash will apply word splitting here
22 ret=($(cat <&3))
23 echo "<ret> ${ret[*]@A}"
24  
25 # Copy "ret" into "myarray"
26 # Remove auto escaping bash does when using @K
27 for (( i=1; i<${#ret[@]}; i+=2 )); do myarray[${ret[$i-1]}]=${ret[$i]//\"/}; done
28 echo "<post> ${myarray[*]@A}"
29  
30 for key in "${!myarray[@]}"; do
31   printf '%s = %s\n' "$key" "${myarray[$key]}"
32 done
```

Output:

```
<pre> declare -A myarray=([mainkey]="mainvalue" )
<ret> declare -a ret=([0]="fookey" [1]="\"foovalue\"" [2]="mainkey" [3]="\"mainvalue\"")
<post> declare -A myarray=([fookey]="foovalue" [mainkey]="mainvalue" )
fookey = foovalue
mainkey = mainvalue
```

[Reference for process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

### Update

As mentioned in the comments, there is one caveat here: This solution assumes each value in the associative array has a single word value. E.g. if "foovalue" had been "foo value", Bash's word splitting would have caused all kinds of mayhem:

Output (if foovalue  were set to "foo value" on line 5):

```
<pre> declare -A myarray=([mainkey]="mainvalue" )
<ret> declare -a ret=([0]="fookey" [1]="\"foo" [2]="value\"" [3]="mainkey" [4]="\"mainvalue\"")
<post> declare -A myarray=([fookey]="foo" [mainkey]="mainvalue" ["value\""]="mainkey" )
fookey = foo 
mainkey = mainvalue
value" = mainkey
```

If you want to deal with this situation while still using this process redirection method, I can think of two approaches:

1. Return the assignment form of the expansion (@A) then use eval to create it.
2. Apply a more advanced parsing before the loop to properly capture the start and end of each variable in the return string.

Here is an example of (1) above:

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
 2
 3 foo () {
 4   declare -n fooarray="$1"
 5   fooarray["fookey"]="foo value"
 6   echo "${fooarray[@]@A}"
 7 }
 8
 9 declare -A myarray
10 myarray["mainkey"]=mainvalue
11
12 # Execute "foo myarray" asynchronously using [process substitution][1]
13 # No need to run it in the background (I.e. using "&")
14 exec 3< <(foo myarray)
15 wait $!
16
17 echo "<pre> ${myarray[*]@A}"
18
19 # Capture the return into a string
20 ret="$(cat <&3)"
21 echo "<ret> ${ret[*]}"
22
23 # Note the returned array is named "myarray"
24 # If you want to overwrite "myarray" with the return entirely,
25 # you can call eval on it directly, otherwise, swap the name
26 ret="${ret[*]/myarray/fooarray}"
27 echo "<rv2> ${ret[*]}"
28
29 # Eval ret into existence
30 eval "${ret[*]}"
31
32 # Copy "fooarray" into "myarray"
33 # Quote to prevent globing or word splitting
34 for key in "${!fooarray[@]}"; do myarray[$key]="${fooarray[$key]}"; done
35 echo "<post> ${myarray[*]@A}"
36
37 for key in "${!myarray[@]}"; do
38   printf '%s = %s\n' "$key" "${myarray[$key]}"
39 done
```

Output:

```
<pre> declare -A myarray=([mainkey]="mainvalue" )
<ret> declare -A myarray=([fookey]="foo value" [mainkey]="mainvalue" )
<rv2> declare -A fooarray=([fookey]="foo value" [mainkey]="mainvalue" )
<post> declare -A myarray=([fookey]="foo value" [mainkey]="mainvalue" )
fookey = foo value
mainkey = mainvalue
```

Comment: Interesting idea. But quite sensitive to special characters. Will break if the value contains space or quotes. You may want to add a warning for that.

Comment: If you make the `seq` from 1 you could shorten line 15 a bit. No need to -1 the end of sequence and when using i here you already have one where you need to +1 instead you can -1 the other. `for i in $(seq 1 2 ${#ret[@]}); do myarray[${ret[$i-1]}]=${ret[$i]//\"/}; done`.

Comment: Both good comments, I've incorporated them both into this last update. Thanks.